# How to implement multiple Reader using db in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

This code is a version of Spring Batch version 1. I have problem migrating this code to version 4 since the org.springframework.batch.item.database.IbatisDrivingQueryItemReader class is no longer available in current version.

The process of the code below is, the withdrawalIbatisKeyGenerator bean should execute first and from the output of that bean, it will use in ibatisWithdrawalReader bean.

My question is, how to implement this reader to current version, since the two bean have dependency with each other.

```
<bean id="ibatisWithdrawalReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.IbatisDrivingQueryItemReader">
        <property name="detailsQueryId"
            value="withdrawalTransactionDao.getWithdrawalTransaction" />
        <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMap" />
        <property name="keyCollector"
            ref="withdrawalIbatisKeyGenerator" />
    </bean>



<bean id="withdrawalIbatisKeyGenerator"
        class="ph.pnblife.julia.batch.BatchKeyCollector">
        <property name="drivingQuery"
            value="withdrawalTransactionDao.getWithdrawalTransactionKey" />
        <property name="restartQueryId"
            value="withdrawalTransactionDao.restartWithdrawalTransaction" />
        <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMap" />
        <property name="parameters">
            <list>
                <value>%%pricing_date_ibatis:date:pricing_date</value>
                <value>%%policy_number:string:pol_no</value>
                <value>%%version_no:string:version_no</value>
                <value>%%start_date:date:start_dt</value>
                <value>%%endt_type:string:endt_code</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="isKeyAMap">
            <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `withdrawalIbatisKeyGenerator` bean could registered as a `StepExecutionListener` where the data required by the reader is generated in the `StepExecutionListener#beforeStep` method.